# Wilcoxon signed rank test vs paired sample sign test

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

so I had an argument with my classmate saying about which test to use, (Wilcoxon Sign-ranked test or Paired Sample Sign test). I say that Wilcoxon Sign-Ranked test is more appropriate since it has a near-symmetrical data. But he said, to be sure Paired Sample sign test is more appropriate.

I can't convince him or he can't convince me. Is there any other assumptions to look at to choose what type of test to use?

Below is the pic of the boxplot of the data.
[image]

Comment: What is the data?

Comment: Sign test does not use 'relative' positions of data above or below mean, and so generally has poorer power than Wilcoxon SR test. Exactly what assumption of SR test does your classmate fear might not be satisfied?

Comment: @StubbornAtom here is the data https://prnt.sc/10ltoib

Comment: @BruceET he just fear that since the data is not fully symmetrical, it wouldn't be considered to use wilcoxon signed rank test.